# Removal children after key event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take and display input. When I enter a number, for example 4, then my document display numbers in a loop, with the amount depending on the entered number. I tried to make it in a way that if I would want to enter a number again, that would create a new list, and the old list would be removed. The code responsible for this is separated by lines.

```
<div id="get-numbers">
    <label for="input-one">Enter the number</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="input-one">
    <div id="container-numbers"></div>
</div>



<script>
    document.querySelector('#input-one').addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
        var inputOneValue = document.getElementById('input-one').value;
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key == 13){
            if (inputOneValue>=0){
                document.getElementById('input-one').value = ' ';
                //----------------------------------------------
                var getNumbers = document.getElementById('container-number');
                var child = getNumbers.children;
                if (child != 0){
                    var divNumber = document.getElementsByClassName('div-number');
                    getNumbers.removeChild;
                }
                //----------------------------------------------
                else{
                    for (var i=0; i<inputOneValue; i++){
                        var numberLi = document.createElement('DIV');
                        numberLi.className = 'div-number';
                        var numberText = document.createTextNode(i);
                        numberLi.appendChild(numberText);
                        getNumbers.appendChild(numberLi);
                    }
                }    
            }
            else document.getElementById('input-one').value = ' ';
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why not use `elem.innerHTML = '',` on parent element that contain the list to clear it.

Comment: But that will not remove parent permanently?

Comment: You want to remove the parent element and its child?

Comment: Yes but after remove them I want to create new ones, after input new value of loop length and after clickig key 'enter'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript HTML DOM method `removeChild()`, remove the child of the parent element.
To remove a child from the parent, we need to pass the child reference to `removeChild()` method.

The updated script:

```
document.querySelector('#input-one').addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    var inputOneValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-one').value);
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key == 13){
        if (inputOneValue >= 0){
            document.getElementById('input-one').value = '';
            //----------------------------------------------
            var getNumbers = document.getElementById('container-number');
            var childs = getNumbers.childNodes;
            if (childs.length > 0){
                for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                    getNumbers.removeChild(childs[i]);
                }

                // Alternative but slower
                // getNumbers.innerHTML = '';
            }
            //----------------------------------------------
            else{
                for (var i=0; i<inputOneValue; i++){
                    var numberLi = document.createElement('DIV');
                    numberLi.className = 'div-number';
                    var numberText = document.createTextNode(i);
                    numberLi.appendChild(numberText);
                    getNumbers.appendChild(numberLi);
                }
            }    
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('input-one').value = '';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I've just noticed, that it is not necessary to use a loop. Instead of this I wrote two lines of code. Below getNumbers I wrote getNumbers.innerHTML = '' "; and then programm works best :D